# How do I implement a search system based on a keyword in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

This is my first Stack Overflow post, but I have read quite a few.

I was messing around with Google Sheets when I had the idea of making a search system. Essentially, the way that it would work is that if and only if a cell contains a keyword, it would then search for it in the data spreadsheet. It would then take that data from the data spreadsheet and paste it into the cell with the key. The key would be in the cell directly to the left of the data. In addition, this should also work for an infinite amount of data.

You can find an example here: [Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SwWzEClx_t1zH9kFJz5oGhc4WAMTlD-jRWsjBCoVM-I/edit#gid=0)

I have tried looking at other forum posts as well as the google documentation but can't find what I'm looking for.

Comment: Your data seems incomplete. What data are you trying to search?

Comment: This is just some example data which I added. I would also like it to learn from it and made it more general so I can try to modify and learn from it later.

Comment: @Dodge1: The problem is the example is incomplete

Comment: I have coded a solution to the problem. Thank you all for your help!